# Sitefinity database interactions using ajax calls

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, database, sitefinity

I have created a very simple ajax script to interact with a php file that handles the database ineractions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imgId = $(".imageVoteBtn").attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://myurl.com/getvotes.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {imgId:imgId},
    success: function(data){
        $("#voteCount").text(data);
    }
  })
});
```

The php files are on a completely separate server and for now it works but we need to move our sitefinity project to another host and they don't allow any connections to the outside.

So now my question is how do I correctly setup database interactions using sitefinity, because the current solution was just a quick hack to get the system working at all. As I understand I should use an ASP.NET solution but because I have never used ASP before, also my knowledge about MVC model is very limited so I don't rightly know where to even begin.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: in the context of sitefinity, you'll create a custom widget and include that widget on a sitefinity page. the widget itself is made up of a model, view and controller. your ajax script will be rendered in the view. hope that helps

Comment: In addition to what @GregH said - you may just need to create a simple web api service that uses the Sitefinity API to get the Image by its Id and use that instead of getVotes.php Where do you keep the votes count?